# ExtJS 7.5.0 Combo tpl not working properly

Tags: templates, combobox, extjs7

ExtJS 7.5.0.55 - modern

Combobox template not working properly. It renders template twice. Is it a bug?

Steps:
1-Select an item from combo box
2-Click outside of the combo

You can test it here.
Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3hu1

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why but **forceSelection: true** is solving the problem.